# absolute and relative paths in CYGWIN

Tags: terminal, cygwin

are they same or completely different? relative path works when youre in a folder and youre trying to go 'back' but absolute paths you have to type out the full directory

is there a shorter way around absolute paths rather than typing out the whole directory path everytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the absolute and relative paths are not peculiar of Cygwin.
It works in the same way on Unix/Linux and similar in Windows

of course the relative depends from where you are

```
$ cd /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/
$ pwd
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0
$ cd include
$ pwd
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/include
```

but

```
$ cd /usr
$ pwd
/usr
$ cd include
$ pwd
/usr/include
```

you can use `PWD` or other variables to short the absolute path

```
$ cd /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/
$ pwd
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0
$ echo $PWD
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0
$ cd $PWD/include
$ pwd
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/include
```